# Ubuntu 16.04.1 stuck on starting Plymouth boot screen

Tags: 16.04

It is showing code with ok in brackets and at the end of it it says starting Plymouth boot screen... then it goes down a few lines which are blank. And now it is just blinking like you can type something but you can't. Any ideas and help will be appreciated.